# Performance metric when using XGboost regressor with sklearn learning_curve

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I've created xgboost regressor model and want to see how training and test performance changes as number of training set increases.

```
xgbm_reg = XGBRegressor()
tr_sizes, tr_scs, test_scs = learning_curve(estimator=xgbm_reg,
                                           X=ori_X,y=y,
                                           train_sizes=np.linspace(0.1, 1, 5),
                                           cv=5)
```

What is performance is it using for tr_scs, and test_scs?

[Sklearn doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve.html) tells me that

```
scoring : str or callable, default=None

    A str (see model evaluation documentation) or a scorer callable object / function
 with signature scorer(estimator, X, y)
```

So I've looked at [XGboost documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html) which says objective is `default = reg:squarederror` does this mean results of tr_scs, and test_scs are in terms of squared error?

I want to check by using cross_val_score

```
scoring = "neg_mean_squared_error"
cv_results = cross_val_score(xgbm_reg, ori_X, y, cv=5, scoring=scoring)
```

however not quite sure how to get squared_error from cross_val_score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XGBRegressor`'s built-in scorer is the R-squared and this is the default scorer used in `learning_curve` and `cross_val_score`, see the code below.

```py
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve, cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

# generate the data
X, y = make_regression(n_features=10, random_state=100)

# generate 5 CV splits
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False)

# calculate the CV scores using `learning_curve`, use 100% train size for comparison purposes
_, _, lc_scores = learning_curve(estimator=XGBRegressor(), X=X, y=y, train_sizes=[1.0], cv=kf)
print(lc_scores)
# [[0.51444244 0.70020972 0.64521668 0.36608259 0.81670165]]

# calculate the CV scores using `cross_val_score`
cv_scores = cross_val_score(estimator=XGBRegressor(), X=X, y=y, cv=kf)
print(cv_scores)
# [0.51444244 0.70020972 0.64521668 0.36608259 0.81670165]

# calculate the CV scores manually
xgb_scores = []
r2_scores = []

# iterate across the CV splits
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):

    # extract the training and test data
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    # fit the model to the training data
    estimator = XGBRegressor()
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # score the test data using the XGBRegressor built-in scorer
    xgb_scores.append(estimator.score(X_test, y_test))

    # score the test data using the R-squared
    y_pred = estimator.predict(X_test)
    r2_scores.append(r2_score(y_test, y_pred))

print(xgb_scores)
# [0.5144424362721487, 0.7002097211679331, 0.645216683969211, 0.3660825936288453, 0.8167016490227281]

print(r2_scores)
# [0.5144424362721487, 0.7002097211679331, 0.645216683969211, 0.3660825936288453, 0.8167016490227281]
```

Comment: Love how you set train_sizes=[1.0] in learning_curve, didn't think of that. Its brilliant! Thanks :)